# Using APOPT (MINLP) solver in Openmdao

Tags: openmdao

I have a mixed integer nonlinear problem. I dont want to use any penalty approaches so I am looking for a MINLP solver in Openmdao. Is it possible to use APOPT solver in openmdao ? It isn't available in pyoptsparse driver. Is there any other alternative ? If not how should I go about implementing APOPT in openmdao ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step in making any optimizer available to OpenMDAO is to make it accessible in Python itself. It looks like APOPT is available in Python through the [GEKKO library](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html?highlight=apopt#what-does-gekko-do). So Step 1 is for you to get that library, and figure out how to use it.

Then you can write a driver that integrates GEKKO in OpenMDAO. To do that you will write your own [plugin](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/experimental/plugins.html) that wraps GEKKO. You can search for the [openmdao github topic](https://github.com/topics/openmdao) to see a list of existing plugins for some examples (you can make plugins for anything, not just drivers)

One example driver plugin for is the [OpenMDAO wrapper for the NLopt library](https://github.com/johnjasa/nrel_openmdao_extensions), written by the National Renewable Energy Laboratory.
https://github.com/johnjasa/nrel_openmdao_extensions/blob/master/nrel_openmdao_extensions/nlopt_driver.py

The actual driver code is [here](https://github.com/johnjasa/nrel_openmdao_extensions/blob/master/nrel_openmdao_extensions/nlopt_driver.py), but the full repo is necessary to actually register it as a plugin.

You can also look into the MINLP algorithm [AMIEGO](https://github.com/Kenneth-T-Moore/AMIEGO), which is also available as a plugin. You can read about it in detail [in this paper.](http://openmdao.org/pubs/roy_scitech_2019_submitted.pdf)